# SSRS report server Data issue

Tags: reporting-services

I have deployed SSRS report on Production environment. When 3 or more user run the same report on production then report server load other user requested data.
For Example-

**Below 3 request-**

User A requested Report X with Paremeter A

User B requested Report X with Paremeter B

User C requested Report X with Paremeter C

**Output from SSRS server -**

User A requested Report X with Paremeter A

User B requested Report X with Paremeter A

User C requested Report X with Paremeter C

Note- This problem occur when all the users request report in same time.

Comment: It seems more reasonable to assume the dataset query is somehow written incorrectly or does not properly take into account the parameter being passed to it. Hard for me to imagine that the ReportServer is serving the incorrect reports...in all my experience it always serves what was requested.

Comment: Does your dataset write any temporary working data during processing? It could be table is being shared between the reports. Use #temp tables or table variables to avoid this.

Comment: @Tohmas, If all 3 user request report same time them one report  parameter override with other report parameter. You can try to any report from your side with 3 or more user.

Comment: No answers from anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had same issue, if you are using ReportViewerForMVC from NuGet Package manager which is third party control may cause problem, follow below points

we will re-use code from ReportViewerForMvc and modify as per our need

1
Install-package ReportViewerForMvc and press enter. After few minutes the package will be installed

2
 This installation will add to the project: 2 assemblies (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms & ReportViewerForMvc)to references an .aspx page (ReportViewerWebForm.aspx) and httphandlers settings in the web.config file.

Note: the .aspx page added does not have a .cs file.

You can now use this .aspx page and code everything in controller, but I am using a slightly different path for code reusability and consistency)

Add a new folder ‘Reports” to the project, and then add a new webform .aspx page (ReportTemplate.aspx to the Reports folder

3
[image]

Copy the contents (as shown in fig) from ReportViewerWebForm.aspx and replace the content of ReportTemplate.aspx with this.
Note: Please do not copy @page directive, copy only the highlighted section.
[image]

4

```html
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %> 
  
<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">--%> 
<!doctype html> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"> 
  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
     
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerReport" runat="server"> 
         </asp:ScriptManager> 
  
        <rsweb:ReportViewer  runat ="server" ShowPrintButton="false"  Width="99.9%" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="true" ZoomMode="Percent" KeepSessionAlive="true" id="rvSiteMapping" SizeToReportContent="false" > 
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>                   
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

5 
 The ReportTemplate.aspx will change to this
[image]

6

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportTemplate.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Reports.ReportTemplate" %> 
  
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %> 
  
<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">--%> 
<!doctype html> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"> 
  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
     
</head> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerReport" runat="server"> 
 <Scripts> 
     <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc" Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" /> 
  </Scripts> 
         </asp:ScriptManager> 
  
        <rsweb:ReportViewer  runat ="server" ShowPrintButton="false"  Width="99.9%" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="true" ZoomMode="Percent" KeepSessionAlive="true" id="rvSiteMapping" SizeToReportContent="false" > 
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>                   
    </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

7 
 Next delete the below scripts tag from ReportTemplate.aspx page

```js
<Scripts> 
     <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="ReportViewerForMvc" Name="ReportViewerForMvc.Scripts.PostMessage.js" /> 
  </Scripts>
```

8 
Add additional attributes to the ReportViewercontrol as below

```html
<rsweb:ReportViewer id="rvSiteMapping"runat ="server"ShowPrintButton="false"Width="99.9%"Height="100%"AsyncRendering="true"ZoomMode="Percent"KeepSessionAlive="true"SizeToReportContent="false"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

9 
 Now open ReportTemplate.aspx.cs file and add below code to the Page_load event, you need to the SSRS Server URL and SSRS report Folder path.

```
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 

namespace ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Reports 
{ 
public partial class ReportTemplate : System.Web.UI.Page 
{ 
    protectedvoid Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (!IsPostBack) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
   String reportFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
.AppSettings["SSRSReportsFolder"].ToString(); 

                rvSiteMapping.Height = 
Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(Request["Height"]) - 58); 
                rvSiteMapping.ProcessingMode = 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote; 

                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("SSRS 
URL"); // Add the Reporting Server URL 
                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = 
String.Format("/{0}/{1}", reportFolder, Request["ReportName"].ToString()); 

                rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh(); 
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 

                } 
            } 
       } 
        } 
   }
```

10 
     Add the SSRSReportFolder path to the app settings in the web.config file.

```
<add key="SSRSReportsFolder" value="BIC_Reports"/>
```

11 
     Next, create an entity class ReportInfo.cs under Models folder

```
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Web; 

    namespace ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Models 
    { 
        public class ReportInfo 
        { 
          public int ReportId { get; set; } 
          public string ReportName { get; set; } 
          public string ReportDescription { get; set; } 
          public string ReportURL { get; set; } 
          public int Width { get; set; } 
          public int Height { get; set; } 
          public string ReportSummary { get; set; } 
       }   
    }
```

12
    Next, we will add code to the Controller and the View Pages.  There is no 
    change to the HomeController.cs. Add the following code to Home/Index view 
    page.

```html
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"; 
} 
  
<h2>Reports List</h2> 
  
<a id="ReportUrl_Performance" href="@Url.Action("ReportTemplate", "Report", new { ReportName = "Performance", ReportDescription = "Performance Report", Width = 100, Height = 650 })"> 
    Performance Report</a>
```

13 Next

```
   using System; 
   using System.Collections.Generic; 
   using System.Linq; 
   using System.Web; 
   using System.Web.Mvc; 
   using ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Models; 

   namespace ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Controllers 
   { 
    public class ReportController : Controller 
   { 
       // 
      // GET: /Report/ 

    public ActionResult ReportTemplate(string ReportName, string 
    ReportDescription, int Width, int Height) 
     { 
         var rptInfo = new ReportInfo 
         { 
             ReportName = ReportName, 
             ReportDescription = ReportDescription, 
             ReportURL = String.Format("../../Reports/ReportTemplate.aspx?
             ReportName={0}&Height={1}", ReportName, Height), 
             Width = Width, 
             Height = Height 
         };   
          return View(rptInfo); 
      } 
     } 
    }
```

14 
   Final Step is to open the ReportTemplate view page under Report and add the following code.

```html
@model ASPNETMVC_SSRS_Demo.Models.ReportInfo 
  
<H1> 
    @Model.ReportDescription 
</H1> 
  
<iframe id="frmReport" src="@Model.ReportURL" frameborder="0" style="@String.Format("width:{0}%; height: {1}px;", Model.Width, Model.Height)" scrolling="no"> 
  
</iframe>
```

Comment: Please include the gist of what the link advises to do in your answer. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2378429